# Too many calls of action on product page

Tags: website-design, usability, conversion, call-to-action

On my products page, I have a large image, then next to it I have add to cart. Below the add to cart section, I then have an Enquire Now button. And below that I have click for Live Chat, and below that I have a freephone number.

I am concerned that this may be overwhelming for the visitor now, giving them too many options of what to do. Does anyone have any opinions, experience or ideas on the right calls of action on a product page?

Comment: Do you have analytics on what people actually click on your page?

Comment: I have full analytics, but add to cart is ajax, and enquiry form is a generic enquiry form, I have over 1000 products too, so not easy to see where people are going, plus in my analytics I cannot separate them from the category pages, as the url structure is the same.

Comment: Isn't Enquire Now, Livechat and Freephone number all apart of customer service? Is there a reason why you created three different paths for what appears to me as customer service?

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you should prioritise and distinguish between your calls to action to optimise for conversion.

> The number of appropriate actions will vary from site to site.
>   However, it is not so much the number of actions as the
>   distinctiveness of each.
>
> Source: [10 techniques for an effective ‘call to action’](https://boagworld.com/design/10-techniques-for-an-effective-call-to-action/)

With that in mind:

**A-** **"Add to cart"** is your most important CTA so it should be a button and occupy a prominent position within the layout so it is clearly distinguishable from secondary CTA.

**B-** **"Enquire now"** helps users who are not ready to make a purchase decision learn more about the product, it's use is circumstantial and therefore it's a Secondary CTA. This could take the shape of a link so it does not compete for attention with your primary CTA " Add to Cart" while still offering help for those users who need it.

**C-** **"Live Chat"** has a different function and it's there to facilitate the purchase decision through direct communication. As it satisfies a different function and will cater for queries that touch upon all products it should be persistent and accessible from a unique point in all your product pages.

**D-** **"Freephone number"** compared to **live chat** which can shorten the sales/purchase process and introduce interactivity, the use of the phone channel demands commitment and time from the user and introduces an element of uncertainty (Will I be able to speak to someone quickly), so its better to have it available to the user but "hidden" behind an explicit CTA. This will reduce calls to customer support and encourage the use of the "live chat" channel.

Hope that helps

Comment: Agreed, that is exactly what I a doing, my thought is that it's just too much.

Answer (score 0):

Sales is awesome,

There is an old rule in direct marketing that says essentially, a % of the population will only respond by mail, another by phone, another will only respond by email, etc etc. If your creative doesn't make space for and call attention to these elements then you will lose leads.

So, if you're concerned that there may be too many CTA's then you need to determined the roi of each. If the revenue generated by the Inquiry button, for example, is minimal then you should test a page without it.

If the revenue is about equal from all CTA's then you need to hire a designer and do A/B or multivariate testing to make them fit together in a non-obtrusive way